# I want to change the order of fields in login/registration form

Tags: users

I've user login/registration form in my drupal 7 site. Two links in this form: "Create new account" and "Request new password" are appearing before captcha. And I'm trying to place these links after captcha and before button. How can I achieve this?:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably should hide this fields, and show them with javascript before captcha input value is not empty. Check it with "on change" function:

```
 $('body').on('change', '#CAPTCHA INPUT', function(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and changing the weights of the form elements.